Why doesn't my app minimize when I click its icon on the taskbar?
The application I am developing is a Visual Studio forms application.
When I run it, it works fine and its icon appears in the taskbar, but when I press it to minimize the window it does nothing. However, if I have the app open and I open more apps above it and click on the icon, it brings it to the front correctly.
Does it have to do with how Windows treats my app? or can it be solved from code?
thanks a lot!!
EDIT: code related to window treatment:
public FrmDocuManager_Cliente()
{
    Global.SuperLog("FrmDocuManager_Cliente_New. Inicio");

    InitializeComponent();

    this.Visible = false;
    this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
    System.Drawing.Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Global.anchoPantalla = resolution.Width;
    Global.altoPantalla = resolution.Height;
}

private void FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Enabled = false;

    string pathPrueba = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"themes\DocunectaTheme.tssp";
    ThemeResolutionService.LoadPackageFile(pathPrueba);
    ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "DocunectaTheme";
    bColoresDefault.Tag = "DocunectaTheme";
}

private void FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global.SuperLog("FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Shown. Inicio ");

    this.Visible = false;            

    // code related to visual elements

    this.Enabled = true;
    this.Visible = true;

    Global.SuperLog("FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Shown. Final ");
}


I've removed the [visual-studio] tag because your usage of it here isn't consistent with its usage guidelines (you can hover over a tag to see its usage guidelines). Simply: this isn't a question about the software you're using to author your code. The biggest problem here: your question has no [mcve], so we can't reproduce your problem.  I assume you mean you're using Windows Forms, but it's not 100% clear. Have you perhaps set TopMost = true on your form? Or maybe you're doing something that's blocking the UI thread?

@ProgrammingLlama Sorry for the use of the [visual-studio] tag, I thought it would be relevant to tag the software I use in case by chance the problem came from some property of a graphic element which is adjusted from the visual studio interface.

@ProgrammingLlama  I don't know how I can illustrate that clicking the app icon on the taskbar doesn't minimize it, I think it's self-explanatory. About whether I have declared TopMost = true, I have it declared like this in a window that opens when you start the app if you have not configured it, in the rest of the windows I do not use it, especially on the main screen of the app, which is where you work mainly I don't use TopMost

I do understand what's happening, but it's not like we can just be like "oh yeah it's the flarblewerger." This isn't a common problem that everyone faces. One possibility (as I said) is that you're blocking the UI thread making the application become unresponsive. Without a [mcve] we can't diagnose the problem the code has, and thus can't help beyond vague speculation such as I've already engaged in.

@ProgrammingLlama I have added a lot of code for the methods that process the window

@ProgrammingLlama Good morning, sorry for the delay, I managed to find out why it was not minimized and brought to the front, the colleague who developed the code blocked the Resize control option, by activating it I could solve my problem, thank you very much for using your time to help me, I thank you a lot

Remove the following line from your code:
this.Enabled = false;

Above line disables the form, thus inputs/minimize does not work!

I have removed the line and nothing, it still does not minimize, thanks anyway for responding!

@HugoJiménez can you double verify? because there's nothing preventing minimize apart from that line in your code. Can you share more code?

I only have that line, I have used the search function throughout the project and there is no other like it, I'm going to add another method to the code

Still, I don't see any problem with your updated code. One possibility is some of your function calls are hung like ThemeResolutionService.LoadPackageFile(pathPrueba); or Global.SuperLog("FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Shown. Inicio "); and that may be preventing inputs. Can you also share a screenshot?

Global.SuperLog("FrmDocuManager_Cliente_Shown. Inicio "); It is a method that writes messages to the log, about ThemeResolutionService.LoadPackageFile(pathPrueba); I will ask the creator of that method what makes that line. What do you need a screenshot of? and I do it right now

Screenshot or preferably a clip of your application in action and its behavior.

Good morning, sorry for the delay, I managed to find out why it was not minimized and brought to the front, the colleague who developed the code blocked the Resize control option, by activating it I could solve my problem, thank you very much for using your time to help me, I thank you a lot
